# symbolic link not created: file exists

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

I am installing oracle database in Ubuntu 16.04. I unzipped the file in `/opt`, then I tried to create a symbolic link using

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper
```

but it shows error

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link './sqldeveloper': File exists
```

What should I do?

Comment: Typo? I think you intended to run `sudo ln -s /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper`?.

Comment: yes,I ran the command given in the question above.

Comment: although the code given by Thomas did worked but I really want to how is it different from that of my code given in question,coz I really can't find any difference

Comment: The difference is a space.

Answer (score 4):

**There is space missing in your command.** 
Use this command (also mention by Thomas in comment).

```
sudo ln -s /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper
```